# Checking condition when step is running on schedule in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

We have workflow in `GitHub Actions` which has both types that trigger on event, e.g.pull-request, and on schedule.

Most of the steps are the same except for running test step. What we would like is:

1. On pull-request without specific label provided: execute smoke test
2. On pull-request with specific label OR on schedule: execute full test

The check for label can be done with `contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'full-tests')`.

The question is how to check when the it is run on schedule? From my understanding of the documentation, when on schedule there is no payload for `github.event` for schedule. However checking `github.event == null` doesn't seems to work.

Is there a specific way to check whether it is running on schedule?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you want to use in that case is the `github.event_name` variable, which represents **the name of the event** that triggered the workflow run in the [github context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context).

In your case, to run a job or a step if the workflow run triggered on a scheduled event, you will need to use:

```
if: ${{ github.event_name == 'schedule' }}
```

[Reference](https://www.eliostruyf.com/devhack-github-actions-run-step-schedule/)